# Upload file to Azure blob fails from Electron app

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm building an electron app with Vue.js. I would like my users to download and upload files, these files are kept in an Azure Blob.

I've successfully managed to make the downloads work, but I have an issue with the uploads. I'm using the following code in my Vue component:

```
import { BlobServiceClient } from '@azure/storage-blob'

const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString('connString')
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient('my container name')
const blockBlobClient = await this.containerClient.getBlockBlobClient('name of my blob')
const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.uploadFile('C://dev//animage.jpg')
```

The error I get is 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined', which originates in the uploadFile method:

[image]

It seems that fsStat is not able to parse the filePath I'm giving.

I've tried with different paths, also with `path.parse()` but without any luck. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: That doesn't really look like a valid Windows path. Have you tried with backslashes (and only one slash), like `C:\dev\animage.jpg`? Also - just fyi - you should only use formatted text for things like code/data/errors/etc. For reasons why, see [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

- The reason you are getting `undefined` as an answer because the `fs.stats` is an async function and without passing a callback function it will give answer as `undefined`.
- Now I will suggest you use `fs.fstatSync`  function this is a synchronous function and will return all the stats of the file.

```
const  fs = require('fs');
const  file_fd = fs.openSync('./test.txt', 'r');let  r = fs.fstatSync();
console.log("Size of File : ",r.size);
```

- Here the `r` represents all the stats of the file and you can access the size of the file as `r.size`

[image]

Comment: but this fsStat() function is not my own code, it's from the @azure/storage-blob package so assume it's implemented correctly there?